# I have confused that is this meaning the same? "How do I (verb)" and "How can I (verb)"

Tags: questions

is this meaning the same?

"How do I (verb)" and "How can I (verb)".

Comment: They are very close.  The first is asking "How to do something" - asking for instructions, while the second can have the feeling of "How can I possibly do something" - it can have the sound of someone about to give it depending on context. The first can be used this way too, but I hear it more often as the second.

Comment: The question is way too broad without specific examples and what the problem or concern is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is subtle. "How do I rent a car?" is asking for instructions, what steps to take to rent a car.  "How can I rent a car?" could also be used to ask for instructions, but the word "can" is usually more about having the **ability** to do something.  So you might ask "How can I rent a car?" if you think you aren't able to rent one - for instance, if you know you don't have enough money or there are no car rental places close to you.

Comment: "How can I rent a car" can also be a kind of moral question, with an implied second part like so: "How can I rent a car [when everyone else has to walk to the party]?"